# Can replication occur if DNA is methylated?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, dna, epigenetics, replication

Can a methylated strand of DNA be replicated without removing methylation? Does it make any difference if the strand is methylated or not (during replication)?

Comment: Don't have sources at the moment, but as far as I know: Yes. Methylated DNA cannot only be replicated, but it can also be passed on to subsequent generations as part of the Epigenetic info inherited by the offspring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely.  It's a pretty cool process, actually.  Most ([well...](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/341/6146/1237905)) DNA methylation occurs in the context of what are called **CpG**; that is, a **C** (Cytosine) followed by a **G** (Guanine).  Because C and G are the Watson-Crick pair for each other, the sequence on the opposite strand will **also** be CG.  Usually, both Cs are methylated, which turns out to be rather critical for maintenance of methylation.

DNA replication occurs through a semi-conservative mechanism, which means each old, original strand is copied and paired with a new strand.  The new strand has no methylation on it, however; it is at this point that the enzyme DNA methyltransferase (DNMT1, specifically) comes into play.  DNMT1 finds the CpGs methylated on one strand ("hemimethylated") and methylates the other strand, providing complete inheritance.  [Here](http://www.fbmc.fcen.uba.ar/materias/genmol/bibliografia-1/review%20DNA%20methylation%20in%20mammals.pdf) is a nice summary, and [this](http://www.igh.cnrs.fr/equip/mechali/publications/RevieworiginsNRCMB2010.pdf) is a review that (briefly) summarizes the evidence that CpGs may play a role in irigins of replication (the jury's still out).

Comment: Thanks for the answer !In PCR ,do we always use methyated dna ?

Comment: @biogirl I dunno, do you?  Theoretically your input sequence, if it's straight genomic DNA from an organism, could/should be methylated, but DNA polymerase does no methylation at all; that is done by DNMT1 and others, and is **much** slower than replication.  After PCR, none of your product will be methylated.

Comment: I have never done a PCR :) If I take DNA from an organism like human(whose DNA is naturally methylated) and then deliberately demethylate it, can it get replicated in PCR or in a cell ?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I was trying to say above, you can't.  PCR is pretty straightforward, it's basically just DNA polymerase.  Each strand of DNA is split and copied, over and over.  As I said above, DNMT1 adds methylation, not DNA polymerase, so none of your PCR product would be methylated.  Adding in DNMT1 after each cycle would be prohibitively time consuming.